# Equivalent Dose absorption from Na22 source

Tags: homework-and-exercises, radiation

No idea what exactly the rules are or how I should ask this question, but here's the verbatim quesiton:

"A Na$^{22}$ source has an activity of 100 $ \mu $C. If you handle the source, how big is the equivalent dose on your hands, if all the radiation were absorbed? Assume the volume and density to be 10 x 5 x 1 $cm^3$ and ~1 $g/cm^3$, respectively."

I'm using the SI-system mostly since I live in Norway, but seem to be using $\mu$C for medical radiation. I presume the volume and density apply to the tissue of the hands, and Sodium 22 has mostly positron decay with (I think) energies of 546keV, which makes it have a quality factor of 1. 
And as far as I've gathered the equation I'm supposed to use is $$D_q = qD_E=q\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{W}{V}$$ where $D_q$=equivalent dose, q=quality factor, $\rho$=density, $W$=absorbed energy, and $V$=volume, but I honestly don't know how I'm supposed to find $W$.
If it is as simple as to multiply the activity with the energy value of the positrons, or if I need to find something else entirely.

But if it's the first, then when everything is inserted gives me a dosage of: $2.32*10^{-7} mSv / hour$, seems a bit too low dosage, I feel like it should be higher.
I'm also wondering if [this](http://www2.lbl.gov/ehs/html/pdf/sodium22.pdf) says that I have to consider both the positron decay, the gamma decay AND the two annihilation photons when I calculate my total energy? With the different weightfactors on the decay with the % listed there?

Namely: positron decay=0.546MeV (89,9%), gamma=1.275MeV (100%), annihilation photon=0.511MeV (180%)

Haven't had any classes about this so far so I'm sorta stuck trying to find things on the internet. So any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Yeah, all beta and gamma interaction have quality factor of 1. Guess I should use the 2*511keV photons instead of the positron energy, or should I add the photon energy ontop of the positron energy? As both technically do destroy the tissue...I guess.

Comment: To be precise here, you need to state what country you are working in - the answers will depend on what system of units you are using.  Outside of the US, no-one uses the term "quality factor" (see [ICRP]([link](http://www.icrp.org/publication.asp?id=ICRP%20Publication%2092)), nor is it correct to use the microCurie - but these will not affect your answer.  " it is as simple as to multiply the activity with the energy value" - yes, providing you remember that activity (in Becquerels) is disintegrations per second.

Comment: Suppose I'm "working" in Norway, so we typically abuse the SI system. Quality factor seems to be the wording the professor uses instead of Weighting factor, but he's German again so, and I suppose it's listed as $\mu$Curie because that's what medical spreadsheets list sodium isotopes in. But thanks for your answer! :)

I've also managed to find http://www2.lbl.gov/ehs/html/pdf/sodium22.pdf which seems to indicate that both the positron decay, gamma interactions AND the annihilation photons have a radiation effect, which I suppose I have to weigh them into the equation with the % it says there?

Comment: *"I'm using the SI-system mostly since I live in Norway, but seem to be using $\mathrm{\mu C}$ for medical radiation."* Well, the formal adoption of the $\mathrm{Bq}$ is relatively recent (1975) and the Curie was well established before that. Change is happening slowly. For instance, in 2009 when the Japanese government updated their rules about the importation and movement of radioactive sources they changed the units the specified from micro-Curies to Bequerels as well as reducing all the thresholds.

Comment: A lot of the inertia in these matters comes from textbooks. If you are going to use Leo, then the main unit of activity you see in the book is the Curie. As newer books (or editions) replace the old standbys new kids get trained mainly in the new units and the usage shifts.

Comment: Finally, to be able to write out words in a MathJax equation, you can use the latex command `\text{}` which will get you both Roman type and text spacing.

Comment: Your link also gives you the answer for the dose rate, so hopefully you can get it to agree.

Comment: I presume you mean [this](http://www.springer.com/physics/particle+and+nuclear+physics/book/978-3-540-57280-0) ? Heh, I guess I am one of those kids that are trying to get the paradigm changed. Only had a year of physics at University level thus far so I feel like this assignment is slightly beyond my current knowledge, so thanks for the help! Will try to figure it all out when I wake up tomorrow.